# How to access an object within a list of them?

Tags: python, json, loops, object

So I have a list of objects from an API which looks like this:

```
{
    "1": {
        "artist": "Ariana Grande",
        "title": "Positions"
    },
    "2": {
        "artist": "Luke Combs",
        "title": "Forever After All"
    },
    "3": {
        "artist": "24kGoldn Featuring iann dior",
        "title": "Mood"
    },
}
```

I was wondering how do I run a `for` loop to access each item.

````
def create_new_music_chart(data_location):
    with open(data_location, 'r') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)

for song in data:
    print(song)
 
Returns:
```
1
2
3
````

but when I try doing this to print artist, it doesn't work:

```
for song in data:
    print(song[artist])
```

Result:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Try `print(data[song]['artist'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`song` is the key in the dictionary. If you want to get the artist, you must look up the key `song` in the dictionary `data`, and `artist` should be a string:

```py
for song in data:
    # song is "1"
    # data[song] is {"artist": "Ariana Grande", "title": "Positions"}
    print(data[song]["artist"])
```

Answer (score 0):

`song` is the key, not the dictionary value. Iterate using `values` instead:

```
for song_dict in data.values():
    print(song_dict["artist"])
```

Comment: Oh, I never actually considered this way before, thank you. Very useful for the future.